# What are the prerequities to get in to the Sequence and Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, book-recommendation

I know algebra, number system and basic math. I want to study series. Please let me know what to study(Book or course) before messing with series.

Comment: Sequences and series are often covered Calculus courses at university. At my university, they are covered in Calculus II. A more rigorous development of these ideas can be found in Analysis (aka Advanced Calculus) courses. So, take any prerequisites classes to Calculus (like College Algebra) and you'll be prepared. Or, just open up any Calculus textbook to the section about series and try to work backwards for what you need to know.

Comment: @HiMatt thanks. You mention the textbook. I am self learner. So no basically the course is. I am just following the random topics of mathematics. I am not sure which textbook I should read to cover college algebra. Recommend some resources that so that I prepare myself for sequence and series.

Comment: For free books, try https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html and https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it my be more appropriate to add this as an answer rather than another comment. Since you are a self-proclaimed self-learner, I recommend going to Khan Academy and building your way up to the [*Series* unit in *Precalculus*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:series). The series unit also covers sequences. Khan Academy does an amazing job explaining mathematics at a rudimentary level. Plus, you can gauge what you understand currently through their website and take prerequisite courses if need be. Best of all, Khan Academy is completely free! Perhaps continue onto the [*Series* unit in *Calculus 2*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-2/cs2-series) if you feel comfortable enough, but don't rush it! Learning takes time.

Contrary to my original comment, I would not recommend grabbing any ol' textbook and trying to understand it. Self-study through a textbook is quite difficult when you do not know sufficient mathematics or do not have a tutor/teacher. In addition, most people find reading textbooks to be boring! However, this may not apply to you, so do not be discouraged from finding a textbook if you wish for more rigor.

Comment: Thank you @HitMatt .. That's awesome online academy. I grateful to you for cooperate.